# How to specify separate contact scripts for different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to point my scripts to two different buttons in my html. The scripts both send an email of what the customer entered however both belong to two separate modal forms.

The first form is:

```
!-- Beginning of Pop-up Device Form -->    

                        <div class="btn-buy hover-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"></div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title"  id="myModalLabel">SpryMobile Device Testing</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <form id="emailForm">
                                                <h4>Name</h4>
                                                <p><input name="contactName" id="contactName" class="form-control" type="text" /></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h4>Email Address</h4>
                                                <p><input class="form-control" required name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" type="email" /></p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <h4>Tell us about your operation</h4>
                                                <input type="hidden" value="Device and Meter Testing" id="contactType"/>
                                                <textarea rows="7" cols="20" class="form-control" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn-u" id="contactSubmit" name="contactSubmit"> <i id="contactSpinner" class="icon-spinner icon-spin" style="display:none;"></i></button>
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="alert alert-success" id="messageSuccess" style="display:none;">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                                                    <strong>Thank you!</strong> We appreciate your comments, and will get back to you soon.
                                                </div>
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="messageError" style="display:none;  padding-bottom:35px;">
                                                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                                                    <div style="float:left;"><strong>Sorry.</strong> There was a problem with the server.</div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>


<!-- End of pop-up -->
```

The script that I have associated with this modal form is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#emailForm').on('submit', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            if( ! $("form")[0].checkValidity() ) {
                return false;
            }

            // Disable the submit button
            $('#contactSubmit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#contactSpinner').css('display', 'inline-block');

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST", cache: false, 
                url : "@controllers.routes.Application.contactSend()",
                data : {
                    contactName: $("#contactName").val(),
                    contactEmail: $("#contactEmail").val(), 
                    contactMessage: encodeURIComponent(  $("#contactMessage").val() ),
                    contactType: $("#contactType").val()
                },
                success : function(msg) {
                    // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
                    if (msg == 'OK_SO_UPDATE') {
                        $("#messageSuccess").css("display", "block");
                    }
                },
                error : function(ob, errStr) {
                    $("#messageError").css("display", "block");
                    $("#messageError span.message").text(ob.responseText);
                }, 
                complete: function() { 
                    $('#contactSubmit').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#contactSpinner').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is referencing the scripts by giving the my form an id of "emailForm". However, if I wanted to add a second modal form such as:

```
 <!-- Beginning of Pop-up Professional Form -->    

                        <div class="btn-buy hover-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2"></div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title"  id="myModalLabel">SpryMobile Professional</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <form id="emailForm">
                                                <h4>Name</h4>
                                                <p><input name="contactName" id="contactName" class="form-control" type="text" /></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h4>Email Address</h4>
                                                <p><input class="form-control" required name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" type="email" /></p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <h4>Tell us about your operation</h4>
                                                <input type="hidden" value="Professional" id="contactType"/>
                                                <textarea rows="7" cols="20" class="form-control" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn-u" id="contactSubmit" name="contactSubmit"> <i id="contactSpinner" class="icon-spinner icon-spin" style="display:none;"></i></button>
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="alert alert-success" id="messageSuccess" style="display:none;">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                                                    <strong>Thank you!</strong> We appreciate your comments, and will get back to you soon.
                                                </div>
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="messageError" style="display:none;  padding-bottom:35px;">
                                                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                                                    <div style="float:left;"><strong>Sorry.</strong> There was a problem with the server.</div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

<!-- End of pop-up -->
```

This references the same script since I gave this form the id of emailForm as well. However, for some reason the alerts that are suppose to appear for the second form are not showing up. Any idea what this could be? Will I need to create a unique script for each form?

Comment: Start your troubleshooting by giving each FORM a unique ID. ID's are designed to be unique.

Comment: So if I gave each form a unique ID wouldn't I need to create a unique script for each form? I tried this and for some reason only the first modal form works. The second one still won't show up with anything.

Comment: No tellin' what will happen when we use duplicate ID's. So not an option. How about giving both FORMs the CLASS `emailForm`? Example: `$('.emailForm').on('submit',`. OR if these are the only FORMs on the page, then just: `$('form').on('submit',`.

Comment: It's as if the script searches for the first form in the file and applies the script to that. When I had both forms and was referencing them both to the script the second form wasn't working. However, when I took out the first form the second form started working

Comment: That may be a duplicate ID problem. Did you try using CLASS or plain FORM TAG instead?

Comment: Yep, still getting the same results. The first form works but the second does not.

Comment: Both forms are working for me when I use `$('form').on('submit',`. Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/s7D98/

Comment: It's the "sorry there was a problem with the server" once you press send message on the first form that I am trying to get working on the second form. And that still for some reason isn't working

Comment: Since your code isolated in the jsfiddle works fine, that indicates the problem is in code that gets executed on your end but you've not provided.

Comment: But it seems that the "sorry there was a problem with the server" message doesn't want to show up when you press send message in the jsfiddle

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/s7D98/ ...and response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate ID's violate the specifications and are problematic, but here's a way around that to temporarily repair this code.

```
$(event.target).find("#messageError").css("display", "block");
```

The FORM tag is also malformed. I moved it up to match the bottom form tag (to after the fourth DIV).

(There are many duplicate ID problems yet unresolved, but the above specifies to the program within the event listener which element to reveal.)

The solution is to use class and name attributes where appropriate.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/s7D98/